# wtforms sqlalchemy selectfield generating string instead of boolean value

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, wtforms

I'm trying to insert a record into a database but sqlalchemy is giving me the error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (builtins.TypeError) Not a boolean value: 'True'
```

I'm setting the value in a selectfield using wtforms like this:

```
    seeking_talent = SelectField(
        'seeking_talent', validators=[InputRequired()], coerce=bool,
        choices=[
            (True, 'Yes'),
            (False, 'No'),
        ]
    )
```

and calling it in my html like this:

```
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="seeking_description">What kind of music are you looking for?</label>
        {{ form.seeking_description(class_ = 'form-control', id=seeking_description, autofocus = true) }}
      </div>
```

How can I stop getting this error?

Comment: Can you post your models code?

Comment: Values of a form will always be strings. You get "True", not `True`.

Answer (score 1):

Use coerce like this:

```
dark_theme = SelectField(_l('Theme'), 
                choices=[('', 'Light theme'), (True, 'Dark theme')], coerce=bool)
```